# Are these two statement the same in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax, flex3

```
    if (processedDescriptors)
        return;


    if (processedDescriptors())
        return;
```

The above is what I found through debugging a flex project, is that true?

**UPDATE**:

Is this the magic of `get` keyword??

```
public function get processedDescriptors():Boolean
{
    return _processedDescriptors;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @fms

By using `processedDescriptors` you are actually accessing a getter, i.e.

Acessing `processedDescriptors` is the same as `processedDescriptors()` in this case.

and you're right it is a good feature (finally) in AS3.

Comment: can `public function get processedDescriptors()` still be accessed by `processedDescriptors()`?